# C# DataGridView cannot be edited

Tags: visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control whose data source is set to a LINQ object at run time. Data is being displayed as expected.  However, when I try to edit the data, nothing happens.  I put lines in my code after the grid is populated to look at the contents of my grid's first row and column.  I was surprised to see that the read-only property for the first column is set to True, even though it is set to False in the designer.  Why is this?  Is it a consequence of connecting the control to a LINQ object at run time?

This is a C# windows forms application, develooped using MS Visual Studio 2008

RobR

Comment: I found the following in another [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915426/why-cant-i-edit-the-values-in-my-datagridview-even-though-its-not-set-to-reado):

"How are you binding to your DataGridView? One thing is that if you are using a Linq list as the datasource queried from a database and you do not have the complete object, then the properties are readonly unless you specify "with new" in the select function. There is not a lot of information in your post. I hope this helps."

This seems to match my case, but how does one use "with new"?

Comment: What does your LINQ query returns? Select "with new" means that your Select projects each element into a new object. E.g. `users.Select(u => new User {DoB = u.DoB, Name = u.Name, Rating = u.Rating})`